# Require Common Lisp Timing Function That Can Write to a Stream

Tags: time, io, stream, lisp, common-lisp

I have always used the Common Lisp `time` macro for checking the speed of an implementation.  However, I would like to be able to write the timing output to a stream (file) so that I can do some statistical analysis on it or to filter it in some way.

So far I have not found any commands or libraries that make this possible for me.  I would greatly appreciate assistance with this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
(with-open-file (*trace-output* "/tmp/time.text"
                 :direction :output)
  (time (sleep 1)))
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Rainer, this answers my need perfectly and quite simply.  I did try another way of capturing output that was SBCL specific but couldn't get that to work so this is great.  Thanks again.  Rama

Comment: @JeremyCaney Thank you for this nudge - I confess I did want to mark this as having answered my query but being new to the forum (at least by way of posting queries) I couldn't figure out how to do so!  Even just now I was mystified even after reading your suggestion - but then when I went to at least upvote the response I noted that I only needed to tick the tick mark.  My Mum used to say, "There are none so blind as those who will not see ..."  (I prefer to use "partially sighted" or "unsighted" these days, though.)